# Google Maps API - retrieve my markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Sorry if this question ends up being obvious to some. Suppose I have manually created a map on Google Maps: I have added a few markers at specific coordinates, each one has a description associated. Now, is there an endpoint in the Google Maps API that lets me execute a query to retrieve data about all the markers? Maybe something that would return a list of markers like

```
{
  ...,
  "markers" : [
    { 
      "name" : "London",
      "lat" : 12.34,
      "lng" : 56.78
    },
    {
      "name" : "Paris",
      "lat" : 98.76,
      "lng" : 54.32
    }
  ]
}
```

I am aware that those are not the real coordinates of London and Paris :) Thanks!

Comment: Paris 48.85, 2.35   London 51.50, -0.12

Comment: No there isn't.  Keep references to them in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: there is no way to do this.

Comment: Well, I'm in the same situation as you were a few years ago. Is there really no way around it?

Comment: I haven't been keeping up with Google Maps API very much unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0):

you could get some information with a reverse geocode lookup

What type of information are you looking to get?
I recommend taking a look at the [api documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)